# Analysis of Gaussian mixture probability densities and Gaussian mixture approximations

Tags: probability-distributions, statistical-inference, information-theory, bayesian, parameter-estimation

I am looking for advice on the analysis of Gaussian mixture densities and the approximation of non-parameterizable densities via Gaussian mixture models. Say, for instance, I have some target Bayesian posterior density that does not possess an analytical parameterization (i.e., does not belong to some known family of distributions). I then apply some tractable approximation, e.g., variational inference, moment matching, etc., and the result is a Gaussian or Gaussian mixture pdf that minimizes some measure of dissimilarity for the intractable true Bayesian posterior, typically the Kullback-Leibler (KL) divergence. Is there a method for measuring the accuracy of said approximation that intuits any convenient statistical meaning? For example, say I am comparing approximating the Bayesian posterior by either a three- or five-component Gaussian mixture. The five-component mixture improves the KL divergence to the true Bayesian posterior by 10% vs. the three-component approximation. But does this improvement have any useful interpretation (beyond the abstract decrease in "information loss")? Hypothetically, I could keep adding components and always improve the KL divergence (or any other divergence/distance). Most papers I see just put a cutoff on improvement, e.g., when the change in KL divergence is less than some threshold stop adding components, but the convergence criteria always seem arbitrary. Is there a measure that facilitates a greater understanding of the accuracy of such approximations?

Comment: Are you familiar with the standard statistical interpretation of KL divergence in terms of the power of a hypothesis test? Is it that this interpretation (which in my view effectively tells you something about the number of samples you can draw from your approximation) is not satisfactory, and you want some other measure instead? Ultimately the appropriateness of any measure of approximation quality is dependent on what you want to do with the approximation you develop, do you have a sense of this, and if so would you add it to the question?

Comment: Oh, also, the "stop when the improvement becomes small" is about as standard a heuristic as one can get for optimisation methods that converge in infinite but not finite time (sometimes this is written as "stop when the gradients are small"). So, regarding this, is there some other stopping criterion that you prefer when doing, say, gradient descent? If so, you can just use that instead.